# why does Outlook Desktop give me a Delivery Confirmation in this (replicable) situation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Background: am a new, reluctant user of Outlook Desktop client (would use Gmail as client and Outlook as infrastructure if allowed, but workplace requires Outlook as client as well as infrastructure).

Please click this image to expand it:

[image]

I've noticed an unexpected behavior from Outlook. Unexpected because I didn't configure Outlook to do this, not necessarily that it's irrational (there might be a perfectly rational reason why Outlook does this).

In the image, I am red rectangles, and the "recipient" is blue rectangles.

If, via Outlook Desktop:

- I send someone an email ("1" in the image).
- And then later, I send another email ("2") to the same person: by hitting "Reply" on "1", and changing the recipient in the "To" field from myself to the actual "recipent" (i.e. the other person),

Then:

- Outlook sends me two Delivery Confirmations for the second email ("2"). The Delivery Confirmations are marked "3" and "4".
- Also note that it adds a scary looking red flag to email "2".

My Questions:

- Why would Outlook do this?
- How can I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, please go to File > Options > Mail > Tracking, uncheck the box of "Delivery receipt confirming the message was delivered to the recipient's email server"
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Will test it soon. Could you please add "Why" Outlook offers this configuration? I mean the original rationale behind why some would want such behavior only in this specific type of instance (i.e., when I hit "Reply" on an email already sent to that person)?